# Ubuntu MDADM Raid 1 Accidental Zero Superblock

Tags: raid, mdadm

I've spent the past 24 hours trying to resolve my issue. While attempted to add another 2 disc raid to my server I accidentally changed the label for one of my drives in the original raid. To further complicate my issue, I accidentally zeroed the superblock on the remaining good drive. I've been having a lot of medical issues lately and I should not have been trying to do this upgrade. But, I'm at a loss for recovering my data, `4TB worth`, with many files not backed up elsewhere.

To recap:

I was trying to setup labels on a new pair of drives (`sdc and sdd`), when I accidentally changed the label of an existing raid drive (`sdb`).

While trying to setup `sdc` and `sdd` as `raid 1` after a failed attempt, I accidentally ran `sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda` on my first raid, which ruined my remaining backup of the data.

I'm not a super expert in Ubuntu, but have gotten by until today. If anyone can help me recover this data I would be eternally grateful. I'm at a total loss.

Comment: Are you familiar with GParted ? Are you using term "label as generic or are you  referring to "LABEL"?

Answer (score 0):

Should anyone find this post, and be in the same situation as me, I was able to fix my issue by using the following command:

`sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --assume-clean --verbose --level=raid1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdX missing`

Be sure to replace the 'sdX' with your own drive!